# find method for String contains check in Python always returns -1 as result

Tags: python, string, find, substring, contains

here is my code,

```
my_string = "PM=1,PmGroup=GNBCUCPFunction_GNBCUCP"
sub = "GNBCUCPFunction_GNBCUCP"
result = my_string.find(sub)
print('line, GNBCUCPFunction_GNBCUCP , Result, ' + str(result))

with open('/app/apollonpm/test_5G/file_list.txt') as f:

for line in f:

    my_string = "PM=1,PmGroup=GNBCUCPFunction_GNBCUCP"
    result = my_string.find(line)
    print('line, ' + line + 'Result, ' + str(result))
```

first part returns expected result while the same if in second part always returns true though the sub string (line) is part of complete string (my_string)

Comment: `line` includes the trailing line break: `\n`.

Comment: what is the part returning true?

Comment: Where is the if statement you are trying to evaluate?